# Using anonymous class in generic method with multiple types

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use an anonymous class in a generic method with multiple types?

```
TReturn DoSomething<TReturn, TInput>(TInput input)
{
   ... do stuff...
}
```

Is there a way to use this method when `TInput` is anonymous?

Example:

```
var ret = DoSomething<TReturn,>(new {Id=27, Name="Test"});
```

Comment: You can always use "dynamic" or "object" as TInput. But what would your function do, if it does not know what the input type is? Does the type information serve any purpose then?

Comment: _"Is there a way to use this method when TInput is anonymous?"_ -- not as written, no. Anonymous types require generic type parameters to be inferred, and type inference works only when the types are present in the _arguments_, not the return type. See duplicate. I agree with the previous comment: since the return type is unrelated to `TInput`, what's the point of having `TInput` in the first place? What is the method going to do with that anonymous type that it can't do with `object`?

Comment: The method user reflection to transform TInput into TReturn.

I Always know the TOutput, and i can always declare it <TReturn>, but i would like to use an anonymous type as TInput